# How to set global header for all feature files in Karate API

Tags: karate

I need to post a request to get an authorization token and include it in the header for all subsequent test requests.  This token changes every time but it is valid for the entire test session as long as I keep sending requests.  In each feature file I can call another feature file to get this token.  But I don't want to do this for every feature file.  I just want to get the token one time at the start of the test and use it for all feature files.  How do I do that?  I've read the Karate information on GitHub but did not find the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second example in the demos answers all your questions: [karate-demo](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo).

EDIT1: Sorry, I read your question too fast. You can use `karate.call()` in `karate-config.js` so it applies to all feature files. I don’t recommend this because you will always have some features where you DONT need this. Just use a call to a feature and don’t over-engineer your tests.

EDIT2: I thought about this a little more, if you are comfortable with Java, you could make a call to a singleton at the start of each feature (or even in the global `karate-config.js`) and in that singleton cache the value of the auth token. So you can do exactly what you need and it will be flexible.

EDIT3: based on this question - we added this functionality to Karate as a `karate.callSingle()` operation, here's the doc: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop#the-karate-object

Comment: Peter, I tried the first method because it's easier and my api requires an authorization for all requests. But I can't get it to work. My karate-config.js looks like this. Please help me.

function() {    
  var env = karate.env;
  karate.log('karate.env system property was:', env);
  
  var credentials = {
 loginName: 'admin',
 password: 'mypassword'
  }
  var token = karate.call('GetTokenId.feature', credentials);
}

The error is:
WARN  com.intuit.karate.ScriptContext - start-up configuration failed, missing or bad 'karate-config.js' - feature call failed, arg: [object Object]

Comment: @bhc sorry, no way i can figure from what you have posted. i suggest first get it working with a normal call at the start of the feature. then graduate to this high level. but just try use the ‘classpath’ prefix for the called feature file name. all the best :P

Comment: It worked just fine after I updated the version from 0.2.7 to 0.6.2.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not sure why my upvote was not taken.  It looks like the first method is not really what I want because the request for the token in karate-config.js is executed for every feature file.  I want the token to be set globally only time at start up and all feature files can use it.  I will have to try the second method.  But this will take me some time because I'm not very comfortable with Java.

Comment: @bhc thanks for the feedback, I'll consider adding this functionality to Karate so you don't need to use Java.

Comment: @bhc there is a new `karate.callSingle()` option and a version 0.7.0.RC1 that you can try - here's the doc: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop#the-karate-object - would be great if you get a chance to validate

Comment: I ran some tests and it worked well.  This is exactly what I need.  Thank you very much for this new option.

Comment: Quoting Peter Thomas: it is possible to to use `karate.configure('headers', { aheader: 'yourHeaderValue' })` for static headers